# Searching first closer value within my dataframe with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have one dataframe with N Timestamps.
I need an additional column 'Timestamp_reached_TP' with those constraints :

- `'Timestamp_reached_TP'` must be the first higher value than `'Timestamp'`
- Additionally, `'Long_TP'` value must be between `'Open'` and `'Close'`

Here is my code below to create the datafrae

```
d = {'Timestamp': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'Open': [100,110,200,200,240,250,300,180,200,200], 'Close': [110,200,200,240,250,300,180,200,200,100],  'Long_TP': [220,220,250,300,400,260,305,200,210,205]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Actual df :

```
   Timestamp  Open  Close  Long_TP
0          1   100    110      220
1          2   110    200      220
2          3   200    200      250
3          4   200    240      300
4          5   240    250      400
5          6   250    300      260
6          7   300    180      305
7          8   180    200      200
8          9   200    200      210
9         10   200    100      205
```

Expected result :

```
   Timestamp  Open  Close  Long_TP  Timestamp_reached_TP
0          1   100    110      220                     4
1          2   110    200      220                     4
2          3   200    200      250                     5
3          4   200    240      300                     6
4          5   240    250      400                   NaN
5          6   250    300      260                     6
6          7   300    180      305                   NaN
7          8   180    200      200                     8
8          9   200    200      210                   Nan
9         10   200    100      205                   NaN
```

I have tried to find a workaround with the left / merge but it does not seem I can join on multiple conditions.

Thank you very much in advance for you help guys !

Comment: YOur output does not make sense. The only rows where Timestamp_reached_TP is between open and close is row 6 and row 8 (if inclusive on he between)

Comment: Well this is the thing, maybe I did not explain so well: I need to search for each long_TP value within the next rows where is long_tp between open & close.

Edit: 

Process for the first row : 
Long_TP = 220, 
row#1 : 220 is not between 100 & 100
row#2 : 220 is not between 110 & 200
row#3 : 220 is not between 200 & 200 
row#4 : 220 IS BETWEEN 200 & 240 

==> row#1[Timestamp_reached_tp] should take the value of the row#4[Timestamp]

And then I need to loop for each row.

Hope it makes sense